# Dual Boot - Windows does not show

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

tldr:

- have SSD + 2 HDD
- tried to install Ubuntu (on HDD) next to Win 7 (installed on SSD)
- couldn't install or 'try'; computer freezed everytime I chose one of those options
- managed to install Ubuntu by turning of ASMedia Controler in UEFI and adding nomodeset (instead of 'quiet splash')
- while booting having problems with "hard resetting link"
- wasted hours; just wanted to go back to 'win-only'
- opened windows partioning manager; looked for the 'linux' partition (which is not recognized by windows).
- deleted it; booted; 'grub rescue', 'no such device'
- noticed I made big mistake (never use windows to delete linux....)
- Re-Installed Ubuntu with this guide: "http://linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/"
- used 'boot-repair-disk' to install new 'grub'
- still no Windows 7 on startup boot manager
- BUT I can use Ubuntu now (but I still have to use 'nomodeset' + turning off ASMedia Controler in the UEFI)
- I can open every harddrive (ssd, too) when I am in Ubuntu. There's still a windows folder and everything else in my SSD.

QUESTION: How do I bring back my Windows 7? 
(also: whats the difference between turning asmedia controller 'on' or 'off'?)

this is what fidsk -l gives me:

Disk /dev/sda: 59,6 GiB, 64023257088 bytes, 125045424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x07c27c6f

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    206847    204800  100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       206848 125042687 124835840 59,5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdc: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xefaf9078

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1             2048 1465141247 1465139200 698,6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc2  *    1465141248 1466118143     976896   477M 83 Linux
/dev/sdc3       1466118144 1943758847  477640704 227,8G 83 Linux
/dev/sdc4       1943758848 1953523711    9764864   4,7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 298,1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x4596a0fe

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 625139711 625137664 298,1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdd: 14,5 GiB, 15518924800 bytes, 30310400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1  *     2048 30310399 30308352 14,5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

PLEASE, let me know if you need any more logs or something else. I am pretty new to Linux.

thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are still trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 , install 15.04 its really easy they even show install alongside windows option . and do you have windows 7 bootloader in another partition ? it should be a 100 MB partition check it. and install ubuntu 15.04 with custom partitioning create /boot and / in different partitions use ext4 it should work fine after installing ubuntu just to be sure it detected the windows type sudo update grub2 see if it shows "windows loader found" if not then do a sudo fdisk -l and post the output :)

Comment: SORRY! I have 15.04 installed. I edited it now. But I used the same guide. I have 3 Partitions. (/, /boot and swap). I can see a 100mb Partition with folders 'boot' and 'System volume information'.

Comment: ok please give an output of "sudo fdisk -l"

Comment: I put it in the question. Any chance to make it look a little less chaotic..?

Comment: my god haha . it sure is chaotic . ok plan B fire up gparted if you haven tried it yet we need to understand where is what

Comment: (sda is SSD) dev/sda1 ist the 105mb boot partition, dev/sda2 is the partition with windows ---------- (sdb and sdc is HDD) dev/sdb1 is just some data --------- dev/sdc1 is /media/abcd/Volume1, dev/sdc2 is '/boot', dev/sdc3 is '/', dev/sdc4 is linux-swap

Comment: interesting i never tried installing windows and linux in different physical storage  .I know you tried all in general but try this once you said you can boot into ubuntu right ?


sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update


sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair


sudo update-grub


sudo grub-install /dev/sdX  <-- linux /boot

Comment: Shantanu Shady.. I just ran sudo update-grub. And guess what happened? It detected the Windows 7 loader. Thank you very much for your help. Now everything worked; also managed to set 'nomodeset' permanently! But one final question: I always had 'hard resetting link' and freezing problems. After I turned ASMedia Sata3 Mode 'off' (in UEFI) I had no such problem anymore. What is this option for? Is it bad to turn it off?

Comment: Glad it worked for you i was thinking more stuff haha and that sata3 it uses additional chips if you have more than 2 sata 6GB/sec ports .. i bet your using z77 chipset anyways . if i was helpful give a vote to my answer, i need more reputation in this forum, haha have a nice day :)

Comment: i have asrock h77 mvp/pro4 motherboard. i dont know how many sata 6 gbit/sec ports I have. Just to make sure I got it right: It has NO negative effect? btw:voted? ty

Comment: im not a hardware expert , haha but i think 2 is the the limit for most boards i think at least was in intel boards and any more than that it uses a chip then ... i think that option is for that . And thanks